# Check for custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, soundcloud

Basically, on my website I'll be embedding two different types of objects, one will be a Youtube embed, one will be a soundcloud embed. I'll be doing this by using custom fields on Wordpress and pulling in through the post_meta.

This is the current code that I have (which pulls in the current 'song' field, which is YouTube)

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'song', true); ?>`

When I try adding that and this:

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'soundcloud', true); ?>`

Nothing actually happens, is there a way to make it so it will check if the fields are null or not and then display the one that is in fact, not null.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
<?php
$song = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'song', true);
if (empty($song)) {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'soundcloud', true);
}
else {
    echo $song;
}
?>
```

should do the trick.  Though if both are null it won't output anything.